# Extract Collection index from ModelExpression

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Is there a way to extract the current index of the collection within a TagHelper?

I want to implement a TagHelper to create a hidden input for "Index" property in a collection where specific indices are missing.

corresp article: [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

He simply extracted the index using regex ([there](https://github.com/haacked/CodeHaacks/blob/main/src/ListModelBindingDemo/ListModelBindingWeb/Helpers/ListModelBindingExtensions.cs)). Is it the only way?

Comment: you may have to look into the source code to see if it's possible to get the index directly ***first***. Even we have the source code but it's not always easy and straightforward to know where the logic is. Sometimes it will take you a lot of time and I think that this case will.

Comment: Ty. That's what I did (looked into the src of linked and asp.net core repo too) and that's why I asked the community...

Comment: actually I don't think you looked into the right place. I don't think it's not that easy. The right place is where the `ViewContext` is constructed together with its `ViewData` and the `TemplateInfo`. If you find the correct place, it should perform some loop over your `IEnumerable` and you can have access to ***the index*** there.  I doubt that the index may be built into the corresponding field name without being exposed via any model or api.